# View dependencies of a module/symbol, for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined widgets and utilities which are used by various packages. I want to track usages of `module` or `module.Widget` across the codebase. I want this to help with easier refactoring.

What can help me with this?

Comment: are you looking for something like a ide feature/plugin or more a build too step?

Comment: @atmd an IDE plugin, as its visual and always on

Answer (score 0):

[Webpack Analyze](http://webpack.github.io/analyse/) might provide everything you need.

[image: Webpack Analyze Tree]

You can navigate up and down from your chunks. So, you have to [lazy load](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/deploying_applications/#lazy-loaded-chunks) your module/widget/whatever and run webpack with `--json > out.json` to generate a file called out.json which contains the metadata that you have to upload to the analyze tool.